# Pyplot / Matplotlib: How to achieve a compressed y-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, data-visualization

I am using pyplot to create a climograph based on the visualization of Walter/Lieth.

[Climograph Walter/Lieth](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klimadiagramm#/media/File:Klimadiagramm_von_Rom_(Italien).png)

[Another Climograph by Walter/Lieth](http://wetter.andreae-gymnasium.de/produkte/allgemein/walter_herrenberg.gif)

As you can see on the images (the links above), the right y-axis is compressed starting from the value of 100. Their visual distance gets smaller while their numerical intervals become larger.

I can't figure out how to achieve this in pyplot. I know how to set the tick values to create a custom scale but of course they always are equidistant. As you can see in my plot the plotted space on the right y-axis corresponds to the interval of the values:
[image: My plot]

Maybe someone could give a hint on how to achieve the effect shown in the two links above.

Cheers!

Comment: Please don't provide the answer in the question. Instead you may answer your own question. I now did that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example for you:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
axes = plt.axes()
axes.set_xlim([-10, 10]) #whatever, optional
axes.set_ylim([0, 1.0]) # whatever, optional
axes.set_xticks([-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
axes.set_yticks([0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100,150,200,300])
plt.plot(x, norm.pdf(x)) #random filler
plt.plot(x, norm.pdf(x, 70.0, 0.1)) #another absolutely random filler
plt.show()
```

My example only shows how you can tweak the Y coordinate ticks, as you wanted to know. Sorry for not being too helpful apparently. I do not understand the downvote at all. There will probably be better answers, I guess.

For actual compression of the samples (data) there are a few ways:

- Use a function to scale the data. Maybe defined in steps. i.e. for 0 < n < 10 leave it as it is, for 10 <= n <100 turn into 11~19, etc.
- Use log scales ( https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/log_demo.html )

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Maybe I was not clear enough with the description of my problem. I know how to tweak the y-axis ticks. What I don't know is how to tweak it to achieve the compression of the axis as seen in the [link](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klimadiagramm#/media/File:Klimadiagramm_von_Rom_(Italien).png) I've posted. In my example plot and in your example code the size of the interval correspond to the plotted space between the ticks. In the link I've posted the space between the ticks stays the same although the interval gets higher. I hope I could clarify my intention.

Comment: Alright, I added a link for insight to log scales. Or you can pretty much relabel ticks and use a function to rescale your data from domain Y1 to domain Y2, or even a combo

Comment: Thank you! I used a function to scale the data as you suggested. It worked. I added an example solution for this to my original post!

Answer (score 1):

*Answer by OP, edited out of their question:*

**Solution**
Here is an example for a solution based on Attersons answer. The scaling function was taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4155197/9773254) answer.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def scale(val, src, dst):
        """
        Scale the given value from the scale of src to the scale of dst.
        """
        return ((val - src[0]) / (src[1]-src[0])) * (dst[1]-dst[0]) + dst[0]

# Actual data
data = [20, 50, 100, 250, 600, 200, 150, 100, 40, 30, 25, 20]

source_scale = (100, 600) # Scale values between 100 and 600
destination_scale = (100, 150) # to a scale between 100 and 150

# Apply scale to all items of data that are above or equal to 100
data_scaled = [x if x < 100 else scale(x, source_scale, destination_scale) for x in data]

# Set up a simple plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.Axes(fig, [0.,0.,1.,1.])
fig.add_axes(ax)

# Set the y-ticks to a custom scale
ax.set_yticks([0,20,40,60,80,100,110,120,130,140,150])
ax.set_ylim(0, 150)
# Set the labels to the actual values
ax.set_yticklabels(["0","20","40","60","80","100","200","300","400","500","600"])

ax.plot(data_scaled)
```

[image: Result]